# MissingFieldException with CodeContracts

Tags: c#, volatile, code-contracts

Once I turned on code rewriter for Code Contracts, I started to see an issue with code that used to work before.

I have a `protected volatile bool` member field that was visible from other assemblies in classes that inherit from mine.  After enabling ccrewrite on my assembly, accesses to that field are now throwing a MissingFieldException.

I know that it is bad style to expose fields in this fashion.  Once I change to expose a property and/or remove volatile marker, problem goes away.

I don't currently have 100% code coverage.

My question is, how can I still rely on Code Contracts, but have my code working as it did before?  How can I find all places where the behavior changed?

Code Contracts version 1.4.50327.0

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Contract Rewriter Version 1.4.50327.0
```

*EDIT* There has been some work done in Code Contracts, but the release notes aren't awesome.  Specifically, it's not clear what's been fixed. I am quoting:

> Release 1.4.51019.0 (October 19, 2012)
>       Fixed more problems with the task manager in VS2012.
>       Fixed a bug in CCDoc.
>       Other miscellaneous bug fixes.
>
> Release 1.4.50910.0 (September 10, 2012)
>       Fixes the task manager so it runs correctly in VS2012: static checker now runs in the background, squigglies are drawn, and contract suggestions appear in the Error List.
>       Updated the installer so that "devenv /setup" no longer needs to be run manually after installation. It is now done automatically as part of the installation. (Which makes the installation take a *lot* longer...)
>       Fixes several bugs in CCDoc.
>
> Release 1.4.50813.1 (August 13, 2012)
>       Bug fixes (everywhere!).
>       Performance improvements (static checker).
>       Precision improvements (static checker).
>       Fixes to installer and build files.
>
> Release 1.4.50327.0 (March 27, 2012)
>       VS2012 support! (But you need to run "devenv /setup" manually after installation!)
>       Bug fixes.

Comment: There's a similar issue that Wayne is having with struct http://stackoverflow.com/q/10542373/90475

Comment: There's a similar issue reported to Microsoft: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/1d398221-f3fb-4048-9a7a-8ee66e9bf5da/#1d398221-f3fb-4048-9a7a-8ee66e9bf5da

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this in the internal release. It will appear in the next release of CodeContracts.

*EDIT*
Here are the release notes from [Code Contracts site](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/releasenotes.aspx):

Release 1.5.60502.11 (May 2, 2013)

- Build script fix to not warn about missing contract reference assembly for C/C++ interop projects
- Fix to VB constructor extraction
- Properly handle generic methods in interface contracts when called from contracts.
- Fix handling of unbox in non-null analysis (avoid a null deref)
- Better handling of nullable and boxing constraints in static checker
- Fix to show setter contracts on F12 (goto metadata)
- More robust checking in implementation of Editor Extension
- Reduced memory consumption and startup time of ccrewrite
- Handle MEF Import attributes in non-null analysis
- **Preserve cross-assembly access to volatile fields in rewriter.**
- Fix a bug in the contract extractor when closures were present in a constructor.
- Fix bug in rewriter when abbreviator method had static generic closure method.
- Support async on pre 4.5 versions of the framework.

Comment: Nice one ;-) I've been more diligent about updating the release notes as I go, so I can just publish them when the release goes out. Do you want a screen shot ;-)